# confused about formatter in numpy. set_printoptions

Tags: python, numpy, formatter

I encountered the following piece of code:

```
z=np.arange(0,12)
np.set_printoptions(formatter=dict(int=lambda x: f'{x:4}'))
print(z)
```

I understand what the code is doing but I am not clear as to what the quantity inside the brackets of dict() is. Without int= we have a function. In numpy docs the value of formatter should be a dict of callables. The keys should indicate the type(s) that the respective formatting function applies to. Callables should return a string. So shouldn't it be int: instead of int=? I got a synatx error when I tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation `int=` is just keyword argument, passed to the method `dict()`, that is equivalent to

```
fmt = {"int": lambda x: f'{x:4}'}
```

---

Other example

```
fmt = dict(int=lambda x: f'{x:4}', float=lambda x: f'{x:4}')
fmt = {"int": lambda x: f'{x:4}', 'float': lambda x: f'{x:10}'}
fmt = dict(int=lambda x: f'{x:4}', float=lambda x: f'{x:10}')
fmt = {"int": lambda x: f'{x:4}', 'float': lambda x: f'{x:10}'}

value = 1
print(fmt[type(value).__name__](value))  #    1

value = 1.1
print(fmt[type(value).__name__](value))  #           1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

They keys for the formatter dict should be strings for the corresponding datatype.  check [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) for `formatter` argument.

```
d1 = {"int":lambda x: x}
d2 = dict(int=lambda x: x)
d3 = {int:lambda x: x}

print (d1.keys(), d2.keys(), d3.keys())
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['int']) dict_keys(['int']) dict_keys([<class 'int'>])
```

As you can see, you can use either use `{"int":.....}` or `dict(int=...}`